# How to calculate percentage on a horizontal row basis in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores all the prints that a specific article gets, based on a query on the url. So, for example, each time a user reads an article in articles.aspx?artid=1 it will store one more row, with the article's ID, the user's IP address, the date and time and the URL referer.

I have a SQL consult that will show me how many times an article has been viewed over the last month, and it'll also tell me the total amounts of views and the unique amounts of views (based on the distinct user's IP).

This is the SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[Blog_Stats].[BlogId],
    [dbo].[Blog_Post].[Titulo],
    COUNT(*) AS [Print],
    COUNT(DISTINCT([dbo].[Blog_Stats].[UsrIp])) AS [Unicas],
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(numeric(18,2), (COUNT(*) / @total_prints) * 100)) + '%' AS [TasaImp],
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(numeric(18,2), (COUNT(DISTINCT([dbo].[Blog_Stats].[UsrIp])) / @total_prints) * 100)) + '%' AS [TasaImpUnicas]
FROM [dbo].[Blog_Stats]

INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Blog_Post]
    ON [dbo].[Blog_Post].[ID] = [dbo].[Blog_Stats].[BlogId] 

WHERE
    ([dbo].[Blog_Stats].[FechaPrint] BETWEEN @f1 AND @f2)

GROUP BY
    [dbo].[Blog_Stats].[BlogId],
    [dbo].[Blog_Post].[Titulo]
```

That'll bring back this table:

```
BlogId  Titulo                  Print   Unicas      TasaImp     TasaImpUnicas
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Art. 1                  20      7           8.97%       3.14%
2       Art. 2                  20      6           8.97%       2.69%
3       Art. 3                  9       5           4.04%       2.24%
4       Art. 4                  17      5           7.62%       2.24%
5       Art. 5                  155     113         69.51%      50.67%
8       Art. 6                  2       1           0.90%       0.45%
```

I need a consult that allows me to calculate the real lecture rate, by making this operation:

```
(Unicas / Print) * 100
```

So that the table will go like this:

```
BlogId  Titulo  Print   Unicas  TasaImp TasaImpUnicas   LecturaReal
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Art. 1  20      7       8.97%   3.14%           35.00%
2       Art. 2  20      6       8.97%   2.69%           35.00%
3       Art. 3  9       5       4.04%   2.24%           55.56%
4       Art. 4  17      5       7.62%   2.24%           29.41%
5       Art. 5  155     113     69.51%  50.67%          72.90%
8       Art. 6  2       1       0.90%   0.45%           50.00%
```

I've already tried adding this line to the SQL Consult:

```
(COUNT(DISTINCT([dbo].[Blog_Stats].[UsrIp])) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS [LecturaReal]
```

But it will return all the records in that column in 0.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: integer divide by integer will gives you result in integer. Multiply the numerator by 1.0 will convert it to decimal type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation problem is integer division.  Your query would be much easier to follow if you used table aliases:

```
SELECT s.BlogId, p.Titulo, COUNT(*) AS [Print],
        COUNT(DISTINCT s.UsrIp) AS Unicas,
        CONVERT(varchar(10),
                CONVERT(numeric(18, 2), COUNT(*) * 100.0 / @total_prints
                       )
               ) + '%' AS TasaImp,
        CONVERT(varchar(10),
                CONVERT(numeric(18, 2), COUNT(DISTINCT s.[UsrIp]) * 100.0 / @total_prints
                       )
              ) + '%' AS TasaImpUnicas,
         COUNT(DISTINCT s.UsrIp) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS [LecturaReal]
FROM dbo.Blog_Stats s INNER JOIN
     dbo.Blog_Post p
     ON p.ID = s.BlogId
WHERE s.FechaPrint BETWEEN @f1 AND @f2
GROUP BY s.BlogId, p.Titulo;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make a query easier to write.
- There is no need to escape all names.  That just makes the query harder to write and to read.
- `DISTINCT` is not a function, so it is misleading to put the following expression in parentheses.
- Multiplying by `100.0` is a convenient way to avoid integer division.